# What happened to Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT?

Tags: google-chrome, dom, html5-fullscreen, webkitrequestfullscreen

According to various sources, [including the Chrome developers](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/let-your-content-do-the-talking-fullscreen-api/), the following should make an element fullscreen with support for keyboard events:

```
myElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't. The element is made fullscreen, but my `keydown` event listeners aren't triggered. A quick inspection shows that `Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT` is `undefined`. Ah...

- Was this functionality removed? Looks like it, but I haven't been able to find any online article or release note mentioning this. Nor found anybody else having the same problem.
- Or is this a red herring, was it always `undefined`, and is my bug somewhere else?

I'm on Chrome 108.0.5359.124, Linux.